# c# Mainform doesn't take variables

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner in c# and I have a problem with MainForm taking values from Strings or something.

For example:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public string Spieler { get; set;}

    void MainFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LogTextBox.AppendText ("\r\nHello "+Spieler); // works nicely
    }

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LogTextBox.AppendText ("\r\nHello "+Spieler); // don't because nothing in ()
    }
```

If I try to set the `public MainForm()` also to `public MainForm(object sender, EventArgs e)` I get an error

> (c# - error cs1729 doesn't contain a constructor)

Even with `public MainForm(string Spieler)` I get the same error.

### EDIT:

I start the mainform with the values in this way:

```
LogDatei = evelogdir+"\\"+((KeyValuePair<string, string>)CharacterSelectBox.SelectedItem).Key; 
MainForm ueber = new MainForm(); 
ueber.SpielerDatei = LogDatei; 
ueber.Spieler = ((KeyValuePair<string, string>)CharacterSelectBox.SelectedItem).Value; 
ueber.Show(); 
this.Hide();
```

Comment: please explain more, what is the error you are getting, the expected output!

Comment: Can you explain more what you're trying to accomplish?  The empty `Spieler` variable in `MainForm()` is "correct" behavior according to the way Forms initialization works;  we'll need to know what you're trying to do to help you get there.

Comment: First please make sure the code you have shown is the exact code you are running. Then please show the code that creates a new `MainForm`.

Comment: `MainFormLoad` is an event handler, and `MainForm()` is the class constructor. An event is _attached_ to a control, which is why you pass the `sender` object and the `EventArgs` to the handler, as this special method gets called whenever the corresponding _event_ occurs. Instantiating an object (at which point the constructor is created) is not an event that's attached to a control, therefore you shouldn't pass those arguments to it, which is why it's giving you the error.

Comment: @Sach actually you could take an object and EventArgs as parameters to a constructor. It would make no sense, but I think the problem here is how OP is instantiating the form.

Comment: @Crowcoder agree, theoretically you _can_ pass those, it just doesn't make any sense to do so. Let me change the `cannot` to `shouldn't`.

Comment: sry; i start the mainform with the values in this way:
   LogDatei = evelogdir+"\\"+((KeyValuePair<string, string>)CharacterSelectBox.SelectedItem).Key;
   MainForm ueber = new MainForm();
      ueber.SpielerDatei = LogDatei;
      ueber.Spieler = ((KeyValuePair<string, string>)CharacterSelectBox.SelectedItem).Value;
      ueber.Show();
      this.Hide();

Comment: @Rio1339 please [edit] your question adding the code above. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: thanks sach. i really should learn how to use the formatting stuff before using a "Post" button :( i'm so sorry.

Comment: You still haven't explained what the goal you're trying to achieve and what's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this using the default constructor, MainForm(). I'm not sure why you got an error - I tried it myself and it works.

Also see my example which passes a string value to the constructor.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public string Spieler { get; set; }
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Console.WriteLine("\r\nHello " + Spieler); // I do not get an error here
    }

    public MainForm(string s)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Spieler = s;
        Console.WriteLine("\r\nHi " + Spieler);

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\r\nHello " + Spieler); // works nicely
    }
}
```